# Windows Mobile device states that the assembly System.Windows.Forms 2.0.0.0 cannot be found

Tags: .net, nant, boo

I am a newbie to .NET programming and I'm trying to create a simple Windows Forms application for a Windows Mobile device using the .NET Compact Framework 2.0. I develop using Boo and using Nant to build my application. My application compiles but it won't run. When I launch the application on my devices it states that the assembly System.Windows.Forms 2.0.0.0 cannot be found. Compact Framework is however installed on the device. The application runs fine on a desktop Windows installation.

My source code:

```
import System.Drawing
import System.Windows.Forms

def Main():
    button = Button(Text: "Ok", Location: Point(10, 10))
    form = Form(Text: "Sample", FormBorderStyle: FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,     MaximizeBox: false, MinimizeBox: false, AcceptButton: button, StartPosition: FormStartPosition.CenterScreen)
    form.ShowDialog()
```

My Nant build script:

```
<project name="Sample" default="compile">
    <property name="dir.build" value="./build"/>
    <property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="netcf-2.0"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${dir.build}" failonerror="false"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${dir.build}"/>
        <booc target="exe" output="${dir.build}/Sample.exe">
            <sources basedir="./source">
                <include name="**/*.boo"/>
            </sources>
        </booc>
    </target>
</project>
```

Is there something simple thats wrong with this or have I misunderstood something regarding assembly references? As I said, I'm rather new to .NET development and don't know exactly how assembly references work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Boo doesn't support the compact framework. The Boo.Lang.dll assembly uses functionality not available in CF. That does however not explain the error I have gotten but my best guess is that Nant allows the Boo compiler to use assemblies from the full .NET framework even though I have specified that .NET CF 2.0 should be the "current framework". It is probably my understanding of what Nant means with "current framework" that is the problem.